# Writing a CASE statement in SQL to include multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a fairly straight forward query that looks something like the following:

```
SELECT
  max(case when site_id = 1 then cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary, '$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) end) fd_salary,
  max(case when site_id = 2 then cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary, '$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) end) dd_salary,
  max(case when site_id = 3 then cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary, '$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) end) ss_salary
FROM mytable 
WHERE gamedate = '2014-07-01'
GROUP BY player_id;
```

This works as intended. I have a `salary` column in `mytable` and I'm trying to get all `salaries` for a `player_id` into one row when I run my select statement since right now they are stored in their own rows. My question is the following: How do I add one more column to this select statement besides `salary`? I'd like to be able to do the same for the `position` column in addition to the `salary` column. I'm not sure if I can mix it into the existing case statements or if I have to add three more case statement for each player. If I didn't combine it with `salary` it would probably look like:

```
SELECT max(case when site_id = 1 then position end) fd_position, ...
```

etc. Is there a way to combine these into one query?

Comment: Don't store currency symbols

Comment: ... or any numerical formatting for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Despite its looks, `case` is a *scalar function* that evaluates to a single scalar value. Myself, because I hate repetitive typing, I'd do something like this:

```
select t.player_id ,
       max( case t.site_id when 1 then t.salary   else 0 end ) as fd_salary   ,
       max( case t.site_id when 1 then t.position else 0 end ) as fd_position ,
       max( case t.site_id when 2 then t.salary   else 0 end ) as dd_salary   ,
       max( case t.site_id when 2 then t.position else 0 end ) as dd_position ,
       max( case t.site_id when 3 then t.salary   else 0 end ) as ss_salary   ,
       max( case t.site_id when 3 then t.position else 0 end ) as ss_position
from ( select player_id ,
              site_id   ,
              gamedate  ,
              cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary,'$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) as salary ,
              cast(position as UNSIGNED) as position
       from mytable
     ) t
where t.gamedate = '2014-07-01'
  and t.side_id between 1 and 3
group by t.player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this :

```
 SELECT
max(case when site_id = 1 then cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary, '$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) end) fd_salary,
max(case when site_id = 2 then cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary, '$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) end) dd_salary,
max(case when site_id = 3 then cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(salary, '$',''),' ',''), ',', '') as UNSIGNED) end) ss_salary,
max(case when site_id = 1 then position end) fd_position,
max(case when site_id = 2 then position end) dd_position,
max(case when site_id = 3 then position end) ss_position
from ....
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Is there a way to combine these into one query?

**A:** Each column returned in the SELECT list is a separate expression.

A `CASE` expression returns a single value.

You would use a separate `CASE` expression to return the `fd_position` column, just as your example shows.

(This is a limitation of SQL, not just MySQL.)